# Go - Sending simultaneous emails through goroutines times out - connection reset by peer

Tags: email, go, goroutine

I have 50 goroutines that start with a channel. Then, the process forever loops reading 100 database records at a time and sleeping for 10 seconds in between database calls. As it loops through the 100 email records to send, it passes each record through the channel to one of the 50 worker goroutines, who then sends the email. The problem is, after it goes through about 1000 emails, I start getting errors like this:

gomail: could not send email 1: read tcp 10.2.30.25:56708->216.###.##.###:25: read: connection reset by peer

I have to send out about 50k emails per day. What do you recommend? Here's the main code that processes the email queue and passes each record to the worker through the channel:

```
func main() {

    MaxWorkers := 50
    println("Creating: " + strconv.Itoa(MaxWorkers) + " workers..")
    batchChannel := make(chan EmailQueue.EmailQueueObj)

    for i := 0; i < MaxWorkers; i++ {
        go startWorker(batchChannel)
    }

    for {
        println("Getting queue..")
        data, _ := EmailQueue.GetQueue() //returns 100 database records

        println("Reading through " + strconv.Itoa(len(data)) + " records..")
        for _, element := range data {
            batchChannel <- element
        }

        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
}


func startWorker(channel chan EmailQueue.EmailQueueObj) {
    var s gomail.SendCloser
    var err error
    open := false
    for obj := range channel {
        if !open {
            s, err = dialer.Dial()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
                return
            } else {
                sendEmail(obj, &s)
            }
        } else {
            sendEmail(obj, &s)
        }
        open = true
    }
    s.Close()
}

func sendEmail(obj EmailQueue.EmailQueueObj, s *gomail.SendCloser) {

    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", "example@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("To", obj.Recipient)
    m.SetHeader("Subject", obj.Subject.String)
    m.SetBody("text/html", obj.HTML.String)

    // Send the email
    response := ""
    status := ""
    if err := gomail.Send(*s, m); err != nil {
        response = err.Error()
        status = "error"
    } else {
        response = "Email sent"
        status = "sent"
    }
    m.Reset()

    return
}
```

I am using the library [gomail](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail) to send the emails. I am open to anything, even a new library or method to send these emails. But, what I'm doing currently is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Honestly working with emails directly is hell... It would be about $600/m with your volume, but you might find [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) amicable

Comment: The remote server is resetting your connection, probably to stop you from sending emails at the rate you're attempting. You have to make sure you are working within the limits of the remote server too.

Comment: What remote server are referring to resetting the connection? I agree, that's what the error message suggests, but every individual email goes to a different address so it's not the same remote server.

Comment: you're not showing how you initialize `dialer`, but I assume it's dialing the same host every time.

Comment: You were right. I contacted our provider and found out their limits which is 30 simultaneous connections and 1,000 emails per connection per minute. So, I have reduced the number of workers to 20 and am resetting each worker's connection after they have sent 900 emails. Everything is working great. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: hi i'm trying to achieve same pls share sourcecode